# Job Titles Standardization process

Tags: python, alteryx

So I am working on something that helps me standardize job titles. So for example, I have Accountant I, Accountant II, Senior Accountant. It should all be renamed to simply Accountant. I need to basically just identify what family the job title comes under, and isolate that value, because I work in the Tax team, and its very important for me to identify the job title parent family and then allocate them under different buckets. For now, I have created an alteryx workflow that helps me do this. But I am open to using newer technologies(preferably open source). 
Please Help!

Comment: What is your question? This seems far too broad/vague.

Answer (score -1):

No matter the tool you use, you will want to use a "Contains" statement. In Alteryx, you can use a formula with `IIF(Contains[Job Title], "Accountant", "Accountant", [Job Title]")`.

If you have a lot of job titles, then it may be best to create a translation table (ie. Input Tool or Text Input Tool) to then say:

```
Job          | Parent

Accountant I | Accountant
```

I hope that helps!